Removing signs from price dataset, but keeping the correct sum
enter image description here
I have the dataset above.
I use:
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[$,.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)

I get prices:
400000, 500000 etc. I need to remove the last two zeros - how can I do this?

Do you have a reason to not remove ".00" instead of "."? Is there a reason you're not doing Math such as rounding on the resulting "removed the dollar sign"? If you're a beginner, that's fine. Just askin'. Good to include that type of detail (if there ARE reasons, of course)

I tried to remove .00 and it removes all zeros. And yeah, I`m a beginner

removing .00 with regex requires alteration as "." is a wildcard character. So an escape character would be required to tell regex that you mean the literal . rather than the wildcard. "." may be useful. So: ".00" could match. But will those digits always be "00"? Really you should be performing math on the number IMHO. That's a bit more effort but not too much. (remove the $, divide by 100, round).

Divide by 100 to remove the last 2 digits.
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[$,.]', '', regex=True).astype(int) // 100

Or remove the digits after the decimal point in the replacement:
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace(r'[$,]|\.\d\d$', '', regex=True).astype(int)

